# How to remove and hide using jquery?

Tags: jquery, hide

Can someone please tell me how to remove and hide a event using jquery ? Actually currently I have using the jquery bellow and its working fine but its just removing the event but not hiding it please can you modify it for me ?

```
function delData(id){
    if(confirm('Do you really want to delete it ? if yes then click OK and wait for next notification please.. ')){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST', 
            url:'manage_reports.php?action=del&id='+id, 
            success:function(result){
                alert('Sale has been deleted successfully.. Do not refresh your page if you want to keep stay here');
                $(control).parents('table').eq(0).remove().hide("table");
            }
        });      
    }
};
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can not `hide` the removed item to just use `hide` or `remove`, If you want to remove some other element then do it separately. [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) does not take selector which you are probably trying to pass, it takes a parameter but its options not selector.

```
function delData(id){
    if(confirm('Do you really want to delete it ? if yes then click OK and wait for next notification please.. ')){
         $.ajax({
              type:'POST', 
              url:'manage_reports.php?action=del&id='+id,
              success:function(result){
                  alert('Sale has been deleted successfully.. Do not refresh your page if you want to keep stay here');
                  $(control).parents('table').eq(0).remove();
          }});
}};
```

Comment: `.hide()` does not take a selector as a parameter.  Don't you want `.hide()` instead of `.hide("table")`?

Answer (score 0):

if by saying "removing event" you mean make an event such as 'mouse click' inactive then i would suggest you first create/bind that event using bind or live on the element

Once your ajax request is done just remove/hide the element and also call an .unBind('event') on it.